# Click a button to copy some text in email without js

Tags: html

I am coding an Invitation mail.

I have a Problem.

How to **click a button to copy some text(invitation code) in email without js** ? yeah. without Javascript.

Comment: No can do sorry.

Comment: As far as I know you have to use some javascript or a flash player solution

Comment: <a href="mailto:xx@yy.com?subject=invitation&body=Free candy invitation code"></a> ?